# According to 1st century Jewish interpretations of Ecclesiastes, what part of man goes to Sheol?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, death, afterlife, kohelet

**Note:** this is an adaptation of the question [According to Ecclesiastes, what part of man goes to Sheol?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/74049/38524) which I previously asked on Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange. On that site the question turned out to be quite controversial -- each answer defends a different view. Here, I want to restrict the scope to how 1st century Jews would have answered the question.

---

Ecclesiastes 3:18-21 (ESV):

> 18 I said in my heart with regard to the children of man that God is testing them that they may see that they themselves are but beasts. 19 For what happens to the children of man and what happens to the beasts is the same; as one dies, so dies the other. They all have the same breath, and man has no advantage over the beasts, for all is vanity. 20 **All go to one place. All are from the dust, and to dust all return**. 21 **Who knows whether the spirit of man goes upward** and the spirit of the beast goes down into the earth?

Ecclesiastes 9:10 (ESV):

> 10 Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with your might, for there is no work or thought or knowledge or wisdom **in Sheol, to which you are going**.

Ecclesiastes 12:5-7 (ESV):

> 5 they are afraid also of what is high, and terrors are in the way; the almond tree blossoms, the grasshopper drags itself along, and desire fails, **because man is going to his eternal home**, and the mourners go about the streets— 6 before the silver cord is snapped, or the golden bowl is broken, or the pitcher is shattered at the fountain, or the wheel broken at the cistern, 7 **and the dust returns to the earth as it was, and the spirit returns to God who gave it**.

Ecclesiastes seems to advocate the bipartite nature of man (man = body + spirit) of Genesis 2:7. And when man dies, the body becomes dust and returns to the earth and the spirit returns to God who gave it (Ecclesiastes 3:20, 12:7).

However, Ecclesiastes 9:10 also tell us that when man dies, he goes to Sheol. And this is when things can get a bit tricky: **What part of man goes to Sheol?**

I see four possible alternatives:

**1. The body goes to Sheol**

If the body goes to Sheol, then what is Sheol to begin with? Is Sheol in the physical realm? Do the molecules of our deceased bodies go there when we die? Does this even make sense?

**2. The spirit goes to Sheol**

If the spirit goes to Sheol, would that mean that Sheol is a spiritual place in the spiritual realm, just as Heaven is? Further, since the spirit returns to God, it would follow that the presence of God is in Sheol or God is in charge of Sheol somehow (see [Intermediate state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_state)).

**3. Man as a whole goes to Sheol**

This alternative doesn't make much sense to be honest. If body and spirit part ways upon death, it wouldn't make sense to say that "man as a whole" goes somewhere, since "man as a whole" (body + spirit) no longer exists.

**4. We go nowhere, Ecclesiastes 9:10 is just being metaphorical**

In other words, there is no longer a "self" that goes anywhere. Man ceases to exist upon death and Sheol is just a metaphorical term for a state of non-being / non-existence (see [Christian mortalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_mortalism)).

**Question**

Which alternative makes more sense and is better supported by Scripture? Are there other alternatives?

---

**Appendix - Pharisees and Sadducees (1st century)**

I am by no means an expert on the afterlife views of 1st century Jews, but at least I understand that the [Pharisees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharisees) and the [Sadducees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadducees) were two major sects at the time with completely different views on the afterlife.

For example, the book of Acts (if you let me quote New Testament scripture) includes the account of an interesting incident involving the Apostle Paul and these two groups:

> 6 Now when Paul perceived that one part were Sadducees and the other Pharisees, he cried out in the council, “Brothers, I am a Pharisee, a son of Pharisees. It is with respect to the hope and the resurrection of the dead that I am on trial.” 7 And when he had said this, a dissension arose between the Pharisees and the Sadducees, and the assembly was divided. 8 **For the Sadducees say that there is no resurrection, nor angel, nor spirit, but the Pharisees acknowledge them all**. 9 Then a great clamor arose, and some of the scribes of the Pharisees' party stood up and contended sharply, “We find nothing wrong in this man. What if a spirit or an angel spoke to him?” 10 And when the dissension became violent, the tribune, afraid that Paul would be torn to pieces by them, commanded the soldiers to go down and take him away from among them by force and bring him into the barracks.
>
> [Acts 23:6-10 ESV]

I think it would be interesting to know how 1st century Sadducees and Pharisees would have answered this question, although I'm completely open to other views from that time (if any).

Comment: Shouldn't you first ask what is Sheol? Both Rashi and Metzudat Zion (classical commentators) understood as the grave. So Ecclesiastes describes the classical Jewish view that the soul goes back to the world of souls while the body decomposes in the grave

Comment: @mbloch - I'm asking a complex question, so yeah, part of the answer must be defining what Sheol was understood to be to begin with.

Comment: Don't all issues disappear once you understand the Jewish definition of Sheol ?

Comment: @mbloch - was there one single settled definition of Sheol in the 1st century? Did the Pharisees and Sadducees share the same definition?

Comment: The sadducees didn't accept the prophets and writings where all references to sheol in the bible can be found. they also didn't believe in an afterlife

Comment: I go to sheol every shabbos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ecclesiastes 12:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes how the body will "return to dust" and the soul will return to G-d.

> And the dust returns to the ground
> As it was,
> And the lifebreath returns to God
> Who bestowed it.

[Rashi, in his commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) to this verse, understands this as a reference to the exile:

> And the dust returns, etc. They came from Bavel and they returned to Bavel.

> And the spirit returns. This is the Holy Spirit, for as soon as the Holy Spirit departed, they were exiled.

However, Rashi cites in his commentary the commentary of the Metzudat David. The [Metzudat David writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) that G-d created man from dust, and so he will return to dust (the body):

> וישוב העפר. הגוף שהוא מעפר, כי תחלת יצירת האדם הראשון היה מן העפר, ישוב אז אל הארץ ולהתהפך להיות עפר כמו שהיה בתחלת היצירה:

However, the soul will return to G-d:

> והרוח. נשמת האדם תשוב אל המקור אשר ממנה נחצבה למעלה, אל האלהים אשר נתנה לו בעת הלידה:

[The Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.7?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en), in his commentary on Genesis 2:7 explains that since G-d "blew into his nostrils", the soul of man is connected to G-ds soul, e.g. the soul of man contains divine essence:

> AND HE BREATHED INTO HIS NOSTRILS THE BREATH OF LIFE. This alludes to the superiority of the soul, its foundation and secret, since it mentions in connection with it the full Divine Name. And the verse says that He breathed into his nostrils the breath of life in order to inform us that the soul did not come to man from the elements, as He intimated concerning the soul of moving things, nor was it an evolvement from the Separate Intelligences. Rather, it was the spirit of the Great G-d: out of his mouth cometh knowledge and discernment. For he who breathes into the nostrils of another person gives into him something from his own soul.

[The Rabbeinu Bahya](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya%7CQuoting&lang2=en), in his commentary on Ecclesiastes 12:7 writes:

> When the Torah writes in Genesis 2,7 ויפח באפיו נשמת חיים, “He blew into his nostrils the soul of life,” this is evidence that seeing G’d blew into man’s nostrils, he received something directly from G’d’s spirit. The meaning of that verse is that some of the nobility of “G’d’s life” was infused into man. He imparted to man part of His own essence so that seeing this part emanated in the emanation בינה which is the source of the concept תשובה, return or repentance, we can understand what Solomon had in mind when he spoke about man’s רוח, “spirit” “returning to G’d who had provided it when his body dies” (Kohelet 12,7). The reason Solomon mentions the attribute האלו-הים in that verse is that the Torah commences with the words בראשית ברא אלו-הים, “at the beginning He created Elohim” i.e. the concept of Teshuvah, (without which the universe could not have endured).

The [Baal HaTurim](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.7?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Kitzur_Baal_HaTurim_on_Genesis.2.7.3&lang2=bi&w2=Tanakh&lang3=en) links Genesis 2:7 to Proverbs 20:27 where it is described that the lifebreath of man, is the lamp of the L-rd.

The Talmud [(Shabbat 152b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&p2=Shabbat.152b.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) seems to confirm the idea that when a person dies, his body will literary return to dust and the soul will return to where it came from, to G-d:

> “And the dust returns to the earth as it was, and the spirit returns to God who gave it” (Ecclesiastes 12:7). This indicates that when the body returns to the earth, the spirit also returns to its place and is no longer aware of what is happening to the body.

It was G-d who gave us our soul, so to Him it will return. See: [Duties of the Heart, Fifth Treatise on Devotion 5:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.12.7?lang=bi&p2=Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Fifth_Treatise_on_Devotion.5.31&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en).

So, to summarize, our soul returns to "the One who gave it", e.g. G-d, while our body returns to where it came from, e.g. the dust.

Please note that these sources are not specifically from the 1st century. However, these concepts may help you out.

I also recommend reading the following article on Aish: [Understanding the source of our soul and its eternal essence.](https://www.aish.com/jl/sp/bas/48942091.html)

And

[Returning Lost Souls from Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380084/jewish/Returning-Lost-Souls.htm)

And

[What Happens After Death from Chabad.org (written by Rabbi Shlomo Yaffe and Rabbi Yanki Tauber)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/282508/jewish/What-Happens-After-Death.htm)

Answer (score 0):

(Psalm 89:49)

"מִי גֶבֶר יִֽחְיֶה וְלֹא יִרְאֶה־מָּוֶת יְמַלֵּט נַפְשׁוֹ מִיַּד־שְׁאוֹל סֶֽלָה׃"

Nefesh (נֶפֶשׁ) = the "soul": which animates the body;  throat, appetite, personality, individual, life of an individual.

Sheol is in reference to a hole in the ground as we see in the perashat of korach, called a grave in English.